How to detect whether user has clicked on “open link on new window” in jQuery
Irrespective of the browser or HTML tag, if a user clicks on “open link in new window” then the user should get redirected to the login page.
I've tried window.opener, but it is not working.
In my website there are different tags where the user right clicks and gets an option to open a link in a new window.
I have some span tags or other tags where the user can get this option.
How can I make this work?

it's hard to understand what you are actually asking.. by window.opener you probably meant window.open(). But first you ask if it's possible to detect if user has clicked.. then you say you have different tags with right click event handlers.. can you please be more clear?

@DiegoD No, the OP probably means window.opener. It 's quite distinct from window.open which is a function.

@traktor oh yes now things got a bit more clear... also the core problem got easier to address now. I was not aware of that window.opener!! Thanks for pointing it out

Why are you supplying links to open something that is not the login page. I suspect that you only want to direct users to the login in page if they are not logged in. If this is correct, please edit the question to say that. At the moment the question doesn't doesn't describe a real problem.

FIRST: IT'S NOT A GOOD IDEA
for a lot of reasons
SECOND: if you still want to do it
Here is an example:
const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (let i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    // only when the user use the context menu
    elements[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        // store the original href
        const originalHref = target.href;

        // change the href redirect the use
        target.href = '/login';

        // change back to the original href
        target.addEventListener('blur', () => {
            target.href = originalHref;
            // remove the event listener to do it just once
            target.removeEventListener('blur', this);
        })
    })
}


Some explanations:
javascript .addEventListener('contextmenu' 
You can detect the contextMenu with this
javascript event.target.href = '/login'; 
Swap the href before the link was clicked
javascript .addEventListener('blur' 
This will detect when the user leaves the context menu and comes back to the page
javascript event.target.removeEventListener( 
Remove the listener because it is useless now
And remember... it's not a good idea

This question has at least one upvote for information about the 'contextmenu` event. The "don't do it because it's a really bad idea" advice remains in place.
